# Are directional derivatives a scalar or vector?

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors, partial-derivative

The name *directional* suggests they are vector functions. However, since a directional derivative is the dot product of the gradient and a vector it has to be a scalar. But, in my textbook, I see the special case of the directional derivatives $F_x(x,y,z)$ and $F_y(x,y,z)$ being treated as vectors. I want a clarification for this.

Comment: It'll give you a scalar if the function is scalar-valued, and a vector is the function is vector-valued.

Comment: As far as i can think of you're interested in $-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}= F_x$ ?

Comment: Elchanan Solomon how can the directional derivative be a vector when it is the dot product of of the grad and a vector? The dot product of two vectors is always a scalar

Comment: @FadelHossamManour The grad acts on a scalar. The result is a vector. Its components are neither scalars nor vectors; they lack indices, as scalars do, but unlike true scalars they're not invariant under orthogonal transformations of Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, we think of the directional derivative of a scalar-valued function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ in a (unit) direction $v\in\mathbb R^n$ at a point $x\in\mathbb R^n$; this is just defined as $$\nabla f|_x \cdot v$$. At a particular point $x$, this is just a scalar; we can also view $\nabla f \cdot v$ more generally as another function $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, assigning to each point $x$ $f$’s derivative in direction $v$ at that point.

In the case that $f$ is a vector-valued function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, we could define a sort of “vector directional derivative” (nonstandard vocabulary) $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ of $f$ at $x$ in direction $v$ by taking the directional derivative of each component function $f_i : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and assembling these into a vector in $\mathbb R^m$. Equivalently, we could take the $m \times n$ *Jacobian* matrix $J(f)$ of $f$’s partial derivatives, whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$; then this “vector directional derivative” is simply equal to $J(f) \; v$, as a matrix product.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the unifying definition is

$$ D_v f(x) := \lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{f(x+vh)-f(x)}h = \left.\frac{d}{dh}f(x+vh)\right|_{h=0}.$$
If $f=(f_1,\dots,f_m)^T$ is scalar valued, this is equal by Chain rule to $\nabla f(x) \cdot v=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\partial_i f(x)$.

If $f$ is vector valued, this is $\nabla f (x) v$ (matrix multiplication of the Jacobian $\nabla f$ with the column vector $v$). In components,
$$ D_v f_j(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\partial_i f_j(x) = \nabla (f_j)(x)\cdot v.$$  This is easy to see from the block matrix representation $$\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix}\nabla(f_1)^T \\ \hline  \vdots \\ \hline  \nabla (f_m)^T\end{bmatrix}.$$

Note the $v_i \partial_i$ in the sum looks like a dot product. It's not uncommon [(e.g. see wikipedia Material Derivative page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative) to write this as
$$ (v\cdot \nabla) f$$
Then $v\cdot \nabla$ is a "scalar operator" acting on the vector field $f$, resulting in a vector field.